# How to send multiple mails at once with

Tags: email, smtp, bulk-email

I am interested how `mailgun` or similar services does send same message to multiple users with one call to user list, like described [here](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203068874-How-do-I-send-the-same-message-to-multiple-users-using-Mailgun-)

Is it just simple loop for each user or there is bulk mailing options for all SMTP servers.
I just want to create my own server for marketing newsletter to our users and was thinking about how to organize sending of mails.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the back end of how specifically mailgun works, but I know when I have needed to do it in the past I have done it with a message, php array of emails and just sent them using php send-mail, just a for-each to loop through the list of emails and they would all be sent right off.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Mark, I think so, I was just wondering is there an option for bulk mailing, though loop is easiest and ordinary way

Comment: Well that is sort of a different question, depends on what language you want to use, what type of server you want to use and whether you want something premade, for example there is lists built into cpanel

Comment: I think this is not depended on languages, though I am using NodeJS, server wanted to use was Postfix.